# Adding Editor Style in IntelliJ WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, editor, webstorm

I recently started working on an Angular project in WebStorm and would like to change the editor style to add more spaces on formatting code with <kbd>CTRL + ALT + L</kbd>.

Currently, when I format my code, all spaces are gone. Here are some places,
[image]
[image]

But I need to have a one indentation between the `{}` or method parenthesis. What I expect is as below:
[image]
[image]

Please help me create this style for Angular / TypeScript development editor. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the ones out there trying to add formatting to their code, here I will post my own answer. You can set custom spacing and styling into your code in intellij IDEs.

Settings -> Editor -> Code Style

Navigate here and you can define custom styling and spacing specific to your programming language and can even export the created styles as an XML file.

[image]